# Indy SOCKET ERROR #1 on MacOS, using IdIcmpClient, works fine on Windows

Tags: macos, delphi, indy, delphi-11-alexandria, macos-sonoma

Hey all im getting "SOCKET ERROR #1" on macos using indy, this code works fine on Windows. Using FMX here.
Using macOS Sonoma
Firewall is turned off on the macOS host.

```
procedure TFrame_PingIPDomain.PingIPDomain;
begin
  memOutput.Lines.Clear;

  IdIcmpClient.ReceiveTimeout := Round(sbTimeout.Value);
 // IdIcmpClient.PacketSize := Round(sbPacketSize.Value);
  IdIcmpClient.Host := edtIPDomain.Text;

  memOutput.Lines.Add('Pings:');
  memOutput.Lines.Add('======================================');

  var AvgTime: Double := 0.0;
  var PingTimes := TList<Double>.Create;

  for var I := 1 to Round(sbPingCount.Value) do
  begin
    IdIcmpClient.Ping();
    if IdIcmpClient.ReplyStatus.ReplyStatusType = rsEcho then
    begin
      var RoundTripTime := IdIcmpClient.ReplyStatus.MsRoundTripTime;
      PingTimes.Add(RoundTripTime);
      memOutput.Lines.Add('Reply from ' + IdIcmpClient.ReplyStatus.FromIpAddress + ': time=' + RoundTripTime.ToString + 'ms');
    end
    else if IdIcmpClient.ReplyStatus.ReplyStatusType = rsTimeout then
      memOutput.Lines.Add('Ping request timed out')
    else
      memOutput.Lines.Add('Ping request failed');
  end;


  PingTimes.Sort;
  for var I := 1 to PingTimes.Count-1 do
    AvgTime := AvgTime + PingTimes.Items[I];
  AvgTime := AvgTime / PingTimes.Count;


  memOutput.Lines.Add('======================================');
  memOutput.Lines.Add('Statistics:');
  memOutput.Lines.Add('======================================');
  memOutput.Lines.Add('Min Time: ' + PingTimes.First.ToString + 'ms');
  memOutput.Lines.Add('Max Time: ' + PingTimes.Last.ToString + 'ms');
  memOutput.Lines.Add('Avg Time: ' + AvgTime.ToString + 'ms');

end;
```

> SOCKET ERROR #1

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, error 1 on macOS is `EPERM` (Operation not permitted). Are you running your app with administrative rights? `TIdIcmpClient` uses a RAW socket, and most platforms (including Windows) restrict RAW socket usage to admins only. This is a known limitation of `TIdIcmpClient`, see: https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/122

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes thank you, that answer sorted out the issue, I reacted to you post of the GitHub issue. I was looking through the issues on Indy before I posted this but could not find anything concrete. had to use Sudo to fix this. This answer also fixed an issue I was having on. windows

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting an answer based on the comment from @RemyLebeau:

`SOCKET ERROR #1` on MacOS means that the **operation was not permitted**.

You need to run your app with administrative rights. `TIdIcmpClient` uses a RAW socket, and most platforms restrict RAW socket usage to administrators only.

So your code is fine, you just need to run your app with administrative rights.

---

And from @GorhinStroebel's comment, if you want to run your app with Admin Permissions on MacOS via the Terminal, you can run:

```
sudo path-to.app/Contents/MacOS/Your_App_Name
```